# What does env_variable=value && command exactly do

Tags: shell-script, shell

I know that I can pass an env variable to a command by prepending it like this:

```
env_variable=value command
```

but today I accidentally put `&&` between the variable and the command:

```
env_variable=value && command exactly
                    ^
                    ^
```

and I got curious how is it different to the correct way. I know that you can use `&&` to chain commands together. **But what's interesting is that the command didn't receive the variable, why?** I'd be grateful if anyone explained how exactly the second variant is different from the first one and why the command didn't see the variable. Thanks

Comment: They're different syntaxes that do different things, both documented in the fine manual. This is like wondering which of `a += 2` or `a *= 2` is the "correct" one.

Comment: rekated https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97302/72456

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
foo=bar && somecmd
```

is pretty much the same as (since the assignment isn't likely to fail)

```
foo=bar; somecmd
```

which is the same as (on separate lines)

```
foo=bar
somecmd
```

which is the assignment of a shell variable called `foo`, and then running a command `somecmd`. If `foo` is not `export`ed (shell variables aren't by default), then it's not presented in the environment of `somecmd`. But you could use within the same shell.

See, e.g.

- [What do the bash-builtins 'set' and 'export' do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71144/what-do-the-bash-builtins-set-and-export-do/71146)
- [If processes inherit the parent's environment, why do we need export?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/130985/if-processes-inherit-the-parents-environment-why-do-we-need-export)

Comment: though note that if the assignment involved a command substitution, i.e. `foo=$(somecmd) && othercmd`, _then_ it would be the success or failure of `somecmd` that the `&&` would test.

Answer (score 2):

You can chain commands in one line via && such that they are executed sequentially - provided that all previous commands run successfully. Each runs in the shell as-is and doesn't modify the shell. Thus each gets the environment variables from the shell it is running in.

```
$ LC_ALL=C && commandB
```

--> execute LC_ALL=C, and if it returns 0 to shell, then execute commandB (with default shell environment)

```
$ LC_ALL=C commandA
```

--> set variable LC_ALL to C and execute commandA with these changes to the environment (effectively making this one command)

Comment: thanks, I know that all, my question is different. updated the question

Comment: (s)he answered your question. if you use `&&` the command will not "see" the env var. If you don't it will.

Comment: @schaiba, _if you use && the command will not "see" the env var_, yeah, ***I noticed that***, that's why I'm asking this question, I want to know *why*

Comment: Because, as answered, "Each runs in the shell as-is and doesn't modify the shell. Thus each gets the environment variables from the shell it is running in." In other words, per the example above, `LC_ALL=C` will run in one shell, while `commandB` will run in the other, each one with its own env vars.

Comment: @schaiba, thanks, so what you are saying is that each command is executed in a subshell and because variable isn't exported it's not available in the subshell environment?

Comment: It's not strictly to do with subshells. The two commands either side of && are set up and executed as different processes (unless, as in this case, one is a built-in). The specific case here is (from the GNU Bash guide) ::: The environment for any simple command or function may be augmented temporarily by prefixing it with parameter assignments, as described in Shell Parameters. These assignment statements affect only the environment seen by that command.